# MySQL Join Unknown column in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am currently trying to join on the same table twice.

I have a table that looks similar to below:

Trip:

```
arrival_loc_code
leaving_loc_code
```

There is another table with the values for those locations:

Locations:

```
location_code (pk)
location
```

I am attempting to to get the location of arrival and leaving based on the location code in trip. My current attempts have lead to :

```
select leavingloc.location,arrivalloc.location from trip 
    join locations as leavingloc on trip.departureloccode = locations.locationcode 
    join locations as arrivalloc on trip.arrivalloccode = locations.locationcode;
```

Leads me to:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'locations.locationcode' in 'on clause'
```

At this point I am pretty sure there is something I am understanding incorrectly and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have aliased your tables but then not used the alias in the join clause, so mysql is getting confused:

```
select leavingloc.location, arrivalloc.location from trip 
    join locations as leavingloc on trip.departureloccode = leavingloc.locationcode 
    join locations as arrivalloc on trip.arrivalloccode = arrivalloc.locationcode;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the name of your alisas is different to what you are using.

change

```
   join locations as leavingloc on trip.departureloccode = locations.locationcode 
    join locations as arrivalloc on trip.arrivalloccode = locations.locationcode;
```

To

```
 join locations as leavingloc on trip.departureloccode = leavingloc.locationcode 
    join locations as arrivalloc on trip.arrivalloccode = arrivalloc.locationcode;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your on clauses, refer to the 'locations' tables by the aliases you've given them (leavingloc or arrivalloc) instead of by 'locations'